# Make filedialog.asksaveasfile open browse window on a default folder

Tags: python, filedialog

I want to let the user choose some file from a default folder using filedialog.asksaveasfile.
The problem is that it will always start at the last folder that the user have chosen.
Is there any way to make to browse window open on some default folder every time?